# What would Komodo Edit's language association be for lesscss?

Tags: komodo, less, komodoedit

I've created a file association of *.less to CSS for editing lesscss files in Komodo Edit. I want this association so that the editor can do quick auto completes, but while it's now correctly complaining about the syntax, is there an extension for the CSS language pattern that will take into account .less' ability to nest and define variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you'd have to write your own UDL.

On their site, they have a tutorial on it:

- http://www.activestate.com/blog/2007/01/adding-new-languages-komodo-udl

And you can inspect all the other UDLs for each of the languages supported out-of-the-box by looking in `{{komodo install dir}}/lib/sdk/udl`

If you do end up writing one, please do share it with the world ;-)

Comment: Nick - I appreciate the direction and I'm sorry I didn't get back to it in time to give you the bounty as the most helpful response. I doubt I'll have the time to get in and create my own UDL but at least now I know where to dig should I feel so inclined in the future.

Comment: ah - I thought I couldn't award the bounty when it had expired - but here you go!

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Komodo 7, it now includes support for both LESS and SCSS.